# I want to change login button to logout if user has logged in.

Tags: php

This is function login() and is_logged_in() function from class.user.php.
I use is_logged_in() to return session that I made on login() function.

```
    public function login($email,$upass) //
{
    try
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM pelanggan WHERE email_pel=:email_id");
        $stmt->execute(array(":email_id"=>$email));
        $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if($stmt->rowCount() == 1)
        {
            if($userRow['status_pel']=="Y")
            {

                if($userRow['pass_pel']==md5($upass))
                {

                    $_SESSION['userSession'] = $userRow['id_pel'];
                    return true;


                }
                else
                {
                    header("Location: login.php?error");
                    exit;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                header("Location: login.php?inactive");
                exit;
            }   
        }
        else
        {
            header("Location: login.php?error");
            exit;
        }       
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex)
    {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
    }
}


public function is_logged_in()
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['userSession']))
    {
        return true;
    }


}
```

in login.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'class.user.php';
$user_login = new USER();

if($user_login->is_logged_in()!="")
{
    $user_login->redirect('index.php?modul=login');
}

if(isset($_POST['btn-signin']))
{
    $email = trim($_POST['email_log']);
    $upass = trim($_POST['password_log']);

    if($user_login->login($email,$upass))
    {
        $user_login->redirect('index.php?modul=login');
    }
}
?>
```

And I use the is_logged_in() function to change button like this, but it didn't work. I have used the other condition , still it didn't work as well. The both of button didn't show, only one of them.

```
<div class="btnmasuk span1">
                    <?php
                    require_once 'class.user.php';
                    $user_login = new USER();

                    if(!$user_login->is_logged_in()){ // I use false condition
                        echo '<a href="logout.php"><button class="btn btn-danger">Keluar</button></a>';
                    }else{

                        echo '<a href="login.php"><button class="btn btn-primary">Masuk</button></a>';
                    }



                    ?>


                </div>
```

How can I solve this? Sorry for my broken english.

Comment: You should create a `SESSION` on login. If this session is not set the use will see the login button, if the user `SESSION['logged_in'] == true` (for example) you can show the logout button. Just use an `if else`. If you need an example just let me know.

Comment: I need an example, can you give the example based on my code? I am sorry, I still understand to implement it to my own code.

Comment: I wrote an example for you. Let me know

Comment: I have implemented on my code, but I get notice about undefined index: logged_in(). I write $_SESSION['logged_in'] =true; above $_SESSION['userSession'] = $userRow;

Comment: The moment a user is loggin in you need to set up `$_SESSION`'s. At this moment you set `$_SESSION['logged_in'] = true`. Then you can use `$_SESSION`'s in all your other scripts. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: The undefined index has solved. I use isset on if statement and it works, and no error anymore. But the button didn't change. The case is same with my code before

Comment: Can you `var_dump($_SESSION);` for me? I want to know if $_SESSIONs are set.

Comment: The result was array(2) {
  ["is_logged_in"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["userSession"]=>
  string(1) "4"
}

Comment: Which mean you need to check on $_SESSION['is_logged_in']; instead of $_SESSION['logged_in'] in your if statement for showing the buttons. let me know :) This should work.

Comment: The both of button have already changed, I am sorry if I bother you. Thanks a lot for your kindness :)

Comment: So it did work? No problem

Comment: Please mark the answer which solved your question as the right answer so your question can be closed.

Comment: Yes, it did. Okay no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Login:**

```
public function getLogin($user, $pass)
{
    // Your query goes here to get Login info based on given $user and $pass. 
    $_SESSION['user_logged_in'] = true;
}
```

**Show button in code:**

```
<?php if( $_SESSION['user_logged_in']): ?>
    <!-- show HTML logout button -->
<?php else: ?>
    <!-- show HTML login button -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

I hope you get the idea about what I mean. You need to optimize your code based on what I wrote above.

Let me know!

Answer (score 0):

You can make a if statement checking if the user has logged in:

Where `u_naam` could be the logged in user value

```
<?php
                    if (isset($_SESSION['u_naam'])) {
                        echo '<form action="includes/logout.inc.php" method="POST">
                            <button type="submit" name="submit">Logout</button>
                        </form>';
                    } else {
                        echo '<form action="includes/login.inc.php" method="POST">
                            <input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="Username">
                            <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="password">
                            <button type="submit" name="submit">Login</button>
                        </form>
                        ';
                    }
?>
```

Comment: Is "u_naam" from column database?

Comment: In this case u_naam is a value i *came up with* for this certain example. You could work with sessions, and those sessions you can call in your if else statement